# Quick Edit in custom posts no show columns after save

Tags: plugins

I have a problem, I create the "post type", custom "metabox" and the columns of "post type", but at the moment of putting 'quick edit' and then save the data the columns are deformed.
The quick edit just want to change the name nothing more, but at the time of recording the data, the columns deform me as in the video: http://recordit.co/AzWRfR46Cp

Comment: Please provide the revlevant code, especially the function where you fill the post list columns and the code which hooks it.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running? I believe this was fixed in 4.7.